# Using smiles strings as database keys

Tags: cheminformatics

I am thinking of using smiles strings as database keys to permit lookups without tracking IDs across various SMILES sources.

Are there any algorithms to compress smiles strings?  Given the limited use of the ASCII character set they could be compressed a ton which would help the lookups.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What's the average length of the keys? Some compression algorithms have a per-string overhead, so short keys will favor methods with low overhead.

Comment: 1) https://www.daylight.com/dayhtml/doc/theory/theory.smiles.html discusses using a lossless compression algorithm: "In addition, ordinary compression of SMILES is extremely effective. The same database cited above was reduced to 27% of its original size by Ziv-Lempel compression (i.e. 0.42 bytes per atom)." 2) http://www.dalkescientific.com/writings/diary/archive/2007/06/25/smiles_states.html discusses a few different algorithms.

Comment: Thanks for the comments!  I do like the ZL compression - it would be nice if someone, somewhere, has defined a canonical dictionary, or has a deterministic, dictionary independent algorithm

Comment: The [zstd](https://python-zstandard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dictionaries.html) compression algorithm has the option to generate a dictionary from a corpus of data, by finding what words/patterns occur most often. You could use this to create a dictionary which is customized to your data patterns.